# How to use Eclipse for Ruby on Rails (RoR)

Tags: ruby, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am new in Ruby. I have installed Ruby on Rails on Windows 7. I visited the following to choose a suitable IDE/Editor for writing Ruby code:

http://rubyonrails.org/download

I found the following Editors for Ruby:

VIM for Rails, RadRails, RubyMine, 3rd Rail, Netbeans for Ruby

I am familiar with Eclipse as I am using Eclipse for java. Can I use Eclipse for Ruby? If so, what configuration is necessary in Eclipse for Ruby project?

Comment: Have you tried the instructions here ? [http://www.easyeclipse.org/site/distributions/ruby-rails.html](http://www.easyeclipse.org/site/distributions/ruby-rails.html)

Comment: This is an old project. They do not support it anymore

Comment: Is there any special IDE for Ruby on Rails?

Answer (score 26):

To save you some legwork, in Eclipse:

1. Go to Help -> Install New Software...
2. Click add (top right of popup)
3. Enter a Name like "RadRails2"
4. Enter the location as http://download.aptana.com/tools/radrails/plugin/install/radrails-bundle (for the full Aptana studio Studio 3, instead enter http://download.aptana.com/studio3/plugin/install)
5. Click ok
6. Restart Eclipse
7. Go to Window -> Preferences. You will see Ruby is enlisted at left panel

You are done...

Now when you use the "New" menu, you'll have the option to make a Ruby project (among other things).

Comment: OP, you've now answered your own question and edited mine. Please also accept my answer and upvote it if you have found it helpful, as the other answer is no longer valid.

Comment: I cannot install it from your address because it seems the package needs other aptana things.

Comment: @BryanWolfford I am using Kepler and it is nearly impossible to use it with Rails. The text shifts around and is never properly aligned. Is there an alternative for eclipse?

Comment: http://download.aptana.com/tools/radrails/plugin/install/radrails-bundle does not work in Luna, it reports Aptana Core missing

Comment: I confirm this solution no longer work on Luna. Is there any other way of installing RadRAils?

Comment: what's the diff between the radrailis-bundle and aptana studio studio 3?

Answer (score 4):

You need to install aptana sudio eclipse plugin and radrails will be included.

refer to this [Cannot Install Aptana plugin on Eclipse 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404760/cannot-install-aptana-plugin-on-eclipse-4-2)

Answer (score 4):

I am using Eclipse Luna and installed Ruby(DLTK) 5.0 kepler from Eclipse Marketplace. I just imported my existing Rails project and seeing it working well with this. I am still exploring it.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Aptana is [largely dysfunctional on Luna](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30500732/is-it-possible-to-update-the-pydev-plug-in-bundled-with-aptana) and there is no wholesale alternative. However, combining the following plug-ins one gets a good degree of support:

- **[TM Terminal](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/tm-terminal)** - provides local and remote command line sessions within Eclipse.
- **[Ruby Development Tools](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ruby-dltk)** - the reference Ruby editor.
- **[JavaScript Development Tools](https://encrypted.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Feclipse.org%2Fwebtools%2Fjsdt&ei=-UCNVc2oN8r_-AHDzoKQCA&usg=AFQjCNHVrwek8aJrCC8qVNTIU1MQChN2sA&sig2=gqIGlUanAnXlSWEpuqz9SA&bvm=bv.96782255,d.cWw)** - the base JavaScript editor.
- **[EGit](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/egit-git-team-provider)** - the Git integration plug-in.

I run `rails` and `rake` in the command line; I also debug through the command line (e.g. using `binding.pry`). Editing `.erb` files is the trickiest bit, the Ruby editor is ok, but in legacy code I have a great deal of JS in these files; in such cases I use the JavaScript Development tools.

With this setup Eclipse runs considerably lighter than with Aptana.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby Development Tools, http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ruby-dltk, is no longer available on marketplace.eclipse.org.

Comment: Indeed, it was deprecated in favour of https://github.com/PyvesB/eclipse-solargraph