# Is it possible to update the PyDev plug-in bundled with Aptana?

Tags: eclipse, aptana, pydev

I have Aptana Studio 3.6.0 installed on Luna 4.4.2 (running on Ubuntu 15.04 64 bit). Aptana bundles in a considerably old version of PyDev (3.0.0) that is largely non functional [due to this bug](https://sw-brainwy.rhcloud.com/tracker/PyDev/549).

The current PyDev release (4.1) should fix the issues I am struggling with, but if I try to update Eclipse tells me Aptana must be removed.

Is it possible in any way to update PyDev while keeping Aptana installed? Or somehow unbundle PyDev from Aptana?

Comment: you probably can't or have to wait an update of aptana... see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18819954/update-aptana-studio-3-with-latest-pydev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer: no, PyDev can not be unbundled from Aptana. The Aptana plug-in should not be installed on Eclipse Luna.

The long answer: the Aptana plug-in available for Eclipse Luna not only ships with a non-functional version of PyDev, it also breaks various things in Eclipse. I finally quit Aptana yesterday, I just could not continue working without PyDev. After that a number of issues that I thought were bugs with Eclipse suddenly become functional again (e.g. [current line highlight](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1448861/#msg_1448861), [Colour Theme](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1698093/#msg_1698093)). I wish I had removed Aptana sooner.